# How to cast nullable type to non-nullable type (in typescript)?

Tags: typescript

I would like to cast nullable type into non-nullable type.

For example, if I have a type like:

```js
const type A = {b: "xyz"} | null
```

then I would like to extract:

```
{b:"xyz"}
```

by doing like:

```
A!
```

but it doesnt work(of course, `!` operator is for nulllable "variables", not nullable "types").

Could someone help me solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: dees this solve your problem: `type T = NonNullable<{b: "xyz"} | null>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a type:

```
type A = {b: "xyz"} | null
```

Using [`NonNullable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) will remove both `null` and `undefined` from your union type:

```
type NonNullableA = NonNullable<A>
```

If you want to only remove `null` but still keep `undefined` you can use [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers):

```
type NullExcludedA = Exclude<A, null>
```

In this case both `NonNullableA` and `NullExcludedA` will yield the type you seek:

```
{b:"xyz"}
```

Comment: extra: `!` uses `NonNullable<T>` behind the scenes.